# Compare randomly generated string to an existing list of strings

Tags: python, recursion

I have a form that expects a unique 5-character ID. I have a function that generates this unique ID. Before entering it in the form, I want to compare it with an existing list of IDs. If the generated ID doesn't exist in the list, pass it in a variable; if it does exist and it isn't unique, generate another ID. What's the best way to go about this?

```py
def generate_id():
    random_id= ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))
    return random_id

existing_ids = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC']
for id in existing_ids:
    if not generate_id() == id:
        unique_id = generate_id()
```

Comment: Works fine for me, where are you stuck?

Comment: EXCEPT just one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debugging**:

```
for id in existing_ids:
```

This denotes the execution of the loop for the number of items in the `existing_ids`, which is definitely not what you want.

```
if not generate_project_id() == id:
    unique_id = generate_project_id()
```

Apart from the incorrect method name, `generate_project_id()` should have been `generate_id()`, this will not do what you think it will, i.e. even if the `id` is unique it will store a different `id` in the `unique_id` since it is calling the method again, `unique_id = generate_project_id()` and who knows it could be a **dupe**!

**Hence**:

If the intention is to keep generating unique id's until one that does not exist in the existing list show up, put it in a loop using `set()` to exclude any dupes in the existing list:

```
import string

def generate_id():
    random_id = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))
    return random_id

existing_ids = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC']    

while True:
    genId = generate_id()
    if genId not in set(existing_ids):
        unique_id = genId
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    a = generate_id()
    if a not in set(existing_ids) : 
        break
```

Comment: Use `while True` instead of `while 1`. It's clearer. Also: `existing_ids` should be a `set` otherwise it's going to take forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string

def generate_id():
  random_id = ''
  random_id = ''.join(random.choice
        (string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))
  return random_id

existing_ids = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC']

unique_id = generate_id()
while unique_id in existing_ids:
  unique_id = generate_id()
  if unique_id not in existing_ids:
    break; 
print(unique_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try bitmap? Because 5 chars could construct a number which < `2**32`, so you can generate a random number [0-`26**6`] and use it to mod 26 to get the only 5 chars,
you can use bitmap to check if it exists.